# Can't apply specific CGColor to CGContextSetFillColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, cgcontext

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor*aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2 green:191 blue:166 alpha:1];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, aColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, rect.size.height/2, 0, 2*3.1415926, 0);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
}
```

the code is used to draw a circle ,but `[UIColor colorWithRed:2 green:191 blue:166 alpha:1]`does't work while `[UIColor blackColor]` works properly.

Comment: try     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 2.0/255.0, 191.0/255.0, 166.0/255.0, 1.0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha` function use a range of `0.0` to `1.0` for `red` `green` `blue` `alpha` attributes.

Your code should be like that:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor*aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(2.0 / 255.0) green:(191.0 / 255.0) blue:(166.0 / 255.0) alpha:1];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, aColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, rect.size.height/2, 0, 2*3.1415926, 0);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
}
```